# A way to calculate points for a surface of a sphere faster than a nested loop?

Tags: python, numpy

Hey Guys at the moment I Have a numpy array representing a Voxelgrid. My Function gets the coordinates x,y,z, the radius and a value. I want to add the values to the Koordinates, that are part of the surface of a sphere for the given radius. I tried to methods, but they are both very slow:

```
def spheric Surface (x, y, z, r, value):
    phi = 0
    while phi <= (2*math.pi):
        eta = math.pi * 2 / 3
        while eta <= math.pi:
            xx = x + r * math.sin(eta) * math.cos(phi)
            yy = y + r * math.sin(eta) * math.sin(phi)
            zz = z + r * math.cos(eta)
            xx = int(xx*resoultion+0.5)
            yy = int(yy*resolution+0.5)
            zz = int(zz*resolution+0.5)
            voxelGrid[xx][yy][zz] += value

            eta += 1/10 * math.pi
        phi += 1/10 * math.pi
```

First method uses sphere coordinates, the bigger the radius is the smaller eta+= has to be.. the method is very slow..

```
def sphericSurface(x, y, z, r, value):
tol = 0.6

grenz = math.pi * 2 / 3
mask = (np.logical_and(np.logical_and((sx[:, None, None] - x) ** 2 + (sy[None, :, None] - y) ** 2 + (sz[None, None, :] - z) ** 2 <= (r + tol)**2,
                                      (sx[:, None, None] - x) ** 2 + (sy[None, :, None] - y) ** 2 + (sz[None, None, :] - z) ** 2 >= (r - tol)**2),
                       (sz[None, None, :] - z) <= (r*math.cos(grenz))))
x, y, z = np.where(mask==True)
z *= 2
voxelGrid[x,y,z] += value
```

Secon Methods uses a mask, but this is also slow.. Is there any better way? and yes my polar angle should only go from 2/3pi - pi..

Comment: FYI your code as posted is not valid Python. The 1st fn also doesn't define `phi` so it must be (inadvertently) using a global variable with the same name for the initial value.

Comment: A general advice: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254475/how-do-i-move-away-from-the-for-loop-school-of-thought

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thank YOu! But i mean the second solution si without for loop... still so slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [python - How do I move away from the “for-loop” school of thought? - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254475/how-do-i-move-away-from-the-for-loop-school-of-thought):

> Normally, data processing in Python is best expressed in terms of
>   iterators... But NumPy turns all that inside out: the best approach is
>   to express the algorithm as a sequence of whole-array operations, to
>   minimize the amount of time spent in the slow Python interpreter and
>   maximize the amount of time spent in fast compiled NumPy routines.
>
> - Work from the inside out: that is, start with the innermost loop and see if can be vectorized; then when you've done that, move out one
>     level and continue.
> - (Keep the original version of the function (which you are confident is correct) so that you can test it against your improved versions both for correctness and speed.)

---

So, let's see:

```
xx = x + r * math.sin(eta) * math.cos(phi)
yy = y + r * math.sin(eta) * math.sin(phi)
zz = z + r * math.cos(eta)
xx = int(xx*resoultion+0.5)
yy = int(yy*resolution+0.5)
zz = int(zz*resolution+0.5)
voxelGrid[xx][yy][zz] += value
```

=> ( capital letters designate vectors )

```
voxelGrid = ceiling (
            [ x + r * sin (ETA) * cos (PHI) ,
              y + r * sin (ETA) * sin (PHI) ,
              z + r * cos (ETA) ] * resolution )
```

---

```
eta = math.pi * 2 / 3                
while eta <= math.pi:
    <...>
    eta += 1/10 * math.pi
```

=>

```
ETA = range ( pi*2/3, pi, pi*1/10 )
```

each value needs to be used repeatedly for each value of `phi` so [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) by the length of `PHI`.

---

```
phi = 0
while phi <= (2*math.pi):    
    <...>
    phi += 1/10 * math.pi
```

=>

```
PHI = range ( 0.0, 2*pi, pi*1/10 )
```

needs to be repeated for each value of `eta` so [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) by the length of `ETA`.

---

Which ultimately results in:

```
# numpy.linspace seems better for your task than arange
PHI = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, np.pi*1/10)
ETA = np.arange(np.pi*2/3, np.pi, np.pi*1/10)

ETA, PHI = np.repeat(ETA, PHI.shape[0]), np.tile(PHI, ETA.shape[0])

XX = x + r * np.sin(ETA) * np.cos(PHI)
YY = y + r * np.sin(ETA) * np.sin(PHI)
ZZ = z + r * np.cos(ETA)

voxelGrid = np.vstack((XX,YY,ZZ))
voxelGrid = np.ceil(resolution * voxelGrid)

# plot it if you want
#import matplotlib.pyplot, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
#fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
#ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
#ax.scatter(*voxelGrid)
#fig.show()
```

Comment: HEY THANK YOU! YOU ARE AMAZING!! but why do i get this error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (80,) 
 i checked it both arrays are 80 long and not 4 and 80

Comment: @Oroshimaru I checked that the code I posted works. Used the following sample data: `x=y=z=0` `r=5` `resolution=10`.

Comment: @Oroshimaru If you tell me the failing line and the shapes of variables involved I'll be able to say more.